# Что-то непонятное происходит с Chronometer в Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Есть Fragment который использую в MainActivity

Activity: **activity_main.xml**

```
  <!--.....-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment4"
    android:name="com.example.tabelkomo.TimerFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:layout="@layout/scoreboard_timer_fragment" />
```

В самом фрагменте находиться Chronometer и Button(при нажатии на которую запускается Chronometer)

Fragment: **timer_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/start"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:contentDescription="@string/button_start"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_play_button" />
<Chronometer
    android:id="@+id/timer_fragment"
    android:layout_width="259dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/digital7momo"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="150dp"
    android:minHeight="50dp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorRed"
    android:textSize="70dp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

FragmentClass: **TimerFragment.java**

```
Chronometer chronometer;
    ImageButton start;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scoreboard_timer_fragment, container, false);
        chronometer =(Chronometer) view.findViewById(R.id.timer_fragment);
        start = view.findViewById(R.id.start);
        Timer();
        return view;
    }
    public void Timer(){
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                long elapsedTime = (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                chronometer.setBase(elapsedTime);
                chronometer.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

При нажатии кнопки start на экране выводятся непонятные цифры

[image: Chronometer]

Если Chronometer использовать в activity_main.xml, то все хорошо работает, а если в fragment то нет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: выглядит так, как будто у вас накладываются друг на друга разные значения. Сначала 00:00, потом становится 00:01, которое накладывается на первое. Так как 00:01 полностью укладывается в 00:00 при таком отображении изменения не видны. потом сверху накладывается 00:02 и "загорается" индикатор посередине, и т.д. Сложно сказать отчего такое происходит. Выложите полностью проект, можно на почту в профиле

Comment: @СпицкоДмитрий можете написать свой комментарий в ответах , вы полностью правы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

выглядит так, как будто у вас накладываются друг на друга разные значения. Сначала 00:00, потом становится 00:01, которое накладывается на первое. Так как 00:01 полностью укладывается в 00:00 при таком отображении изменения не видны. потом сверху накладывается 00:02 и "загорается" индикатор посередине, и т.д.